# Syntax error with recursive SQL query and order by for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I want to get a query with SQLAlchemy on the example query that is shown on the page https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html:

```
WITH RECURSIVE under_alice(name,level) AS (
    VALUES('Alice',0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org.name, under_alice.level+1
      FROM org JOIN under_alice ON org.boss=under_alice.name
     ORDER BY 2 DESC
)

SELECT substr('..........',1,level*3) || name FROM under_alice;
```

I'm trying to execute a my self recursive query that falls into syntax error for SQLite:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error

An exception is raised when SQLAlchemy adds parentheses on time compilation SQL statement for the bottom query in the recursive query, if it uses a orderring. How to remove parentheses from a SQL?

Reproducing the exception:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Category {self.name}>'



import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

db.create_all()
```

Data of Category:

```
data = [
    {'parent_id': None, 'name': 'Everything for rehabilitation'},
    {'parent_id': 1,    'name': 'Wheelchairs'},
    {'parent_id': 1,    'name': 'Wheelchairs 2'},
    {'parent_id': 1,    'name': 'Scooters for the disabled'},

    {'parent_id': 2,    'name': 'Active wheelchairs'},
    {'parent_id': 2,    'name': 'Children wheelchairs'},
    {'parent_id': 2,    'name': 'Children wheelchairs 2'},
    {'parent_id': 2,    'name': 'Wheelchair Otto Bock'},
    {'parent_id': 2,    'name': 'Wheelchair Vermeiren'},

    {'parent_id': 3,    'name': 'Folding wheelchairs'},
    {'parent_id': 3,    'name': 'Wheelchair for disabled people'},
    {'parent_id': 3,    'name': 'Wheelchairs for transportation of patients'},

    {'parent_id': 4,    'name': 'Foldable scooters for disabled people'},
    {'parent_id': 4,    'name': 'Three-wheeled scooters for disabled people'}
]

for param in data:
    db.session.add(Category(**param))

db.session.commit()
```

Query:

```
top_query = db.session.query(Category, db.literal(0).label('level')) \
                    .filter(Category.parent_id == None) \
                    .cte(name='top_query', recursive=True)

top_query = db.aliased(top_query, name='my_category')

bottom_query = db.session.query(Category, (top_query.c.level + 1).label('level')) \
                        .join(top_query, Category.parent_id == top_query.c.id) \
                        .order_by(db.desc(Category.parent_id)) # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

hierarchy_query = top_query.union_all(bottom_query)

db.session.query(hierarchy_query).all()
```

The bottom SELECT with parentheses is error:

```
WITH RECURSIVE my_category(id, parent_id, name, level) AS (
    SELECT category.id AS id,
           category.parent_id AS parent_id,
           category.name AS name,
           ? AS level 
      FROM category 
     WHERE category.parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT category.id AS category_id,
            category.parent_id AS category_parent_id,
            category.name AS category_name,
            my_category.level + ? AS level 
       FROM category JOIN my_category ON category.parent_id = my_category.id
    ORDER BY category.parent_id DESC)
)

SELECT my_category.id AS my_category_id,
       my_category.parent_id AS my_category_parent_id,
       my_category.name AS my_category_name,
       my_category.level AS my_category_level 
  FROM my_category
```

If `order_by` is commented, then the exception is not raised:

```
top_query = db.session.query(Category, db.literal(0).label('level')) \
                    .filter(Category.parent_id == None) \
                    .cte(name='top_query', recursive=True)

top_query = db.aliased(top_query, name='my_category')

bottom_query = db.session.query(Category, (top_query.c.level + 1).label('level')) \
                        .join(top_query, Category.parent_id == top_query.c.id) \
                        # .order_by(db.desc(Category.parent_id))

hierarchy_query = top_query.union_all(bottom_query)

db.session.query(hierarchy_query).all()
```

The bottom SELECT without parentheses (and without order_by) do not a have error:

```
WITH RECURSIVE my_category(id, parent_id, name, level) AS (
    SELECT category.id AS id,
           category.parent_id AS parent_id,
           category.name AS name,
           ? AS level 
      FROM category 
     WHERE category.parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT category.id AS h_category_id,
           category.parent_id AS category_parent_id,
           category.name AS category_name,
           my_category.level + ? AS level
      FROM category JOIN my_category ON category.parent_id = my_category.id
)

SELECT my_category.id AS my_category_id,
       my_category.parent_id AS my_category_parent_id,
       my_category.name AS my_category_name,
       my_category.level AS my_category_level
  FROM my_category
```

Comment: Have a look at the syntax highlighting of your data.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, i'm want to get next a query as shown on page https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html:


WITH RECURSIVE
  under_alice(name,level) AS (
    VALUES('Alice',0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT org.name, under_alice.level+1
      FROM org JOIN under_alice ON org.boss=under_alice.name
     ORDER BY 2 DESC
  )
SELECT substr('..........',1,level*3) || name FROM under_alice;

Answer (score 0):

The reason why SQLAlchemy compiles the query the way it does is that

```
SELECT x FROM foo UNION ALL (SELECT x FROM bar ORDER BY x)
```

and

```
SELECT x FROM foo UNION ALL SELECT x FROM bar ORDER BY x;
```

are different queries (in databases that support the syntax of the 1st query, such as Postgresql):

- the former is a union between 2 selects, of which the second is ordered
- the latter is a union between 2 unordered selects. The compound select is ordered as a whole.

SQLite does not support the syntax used in the former query, hence the syntax error.

In SQLite's implementation of [WITH statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) the ORDER BY when applied to the compound select as a whole has the following meaning:

> If an ORDER BY clause is present, it determines the order in which rows are extracted from the queue in step 2a. ...

So instead of applying an ordering to the second query used in the union as you've done, it should be applied to the compound select used in the CTE, but unfortunately it seems that SQLAlchemy [`CTE`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CTE) does not support this out of the box. You can implement your own function for that:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.selectable import CTE

# Following the implementation of CTE.union_all():
def cte_order_by(self, *clauses):
    return CTE(
        self.original.order_by(*clauses),
        name=self.name,
        recursive=self.recursive,
        _restates=self._restates.union([self]),
        _suffixes=self._suffixes
    )
```

and then use it on your query:

```
hierarchy_query = top_query.union_all(bottom_query)
hierarchy_query = cte_order_by(hierarchy_query, db.desc('2'))
```